# ERROR Error: Must supply a value for form control with name: 'parent_type'

Tags: node.js, angular, database

Must supply a value for form control with name: 'parent_type'

**Error is appearing while editing the form.**

Answer (score 0):

It simply means that you have assigned **'parent_type'** (or any field name which will appear on your console),which is nothing but field name, which you have assigned in your formbuilder.

Step 1:- First check wheather you have that particular field in your **database** table,
         If not then delete it from formbuilder or if you required then add it in your 
         **database** table.

**OR**

Step 1 :- If you have assigned the field in your formbuilder and while creating the data it has not been set, so the error may appear, you can set by using this.FormGroup.PatchValue({**column names**(which appear in your console)});.